# How do I use ArrayList<Integer>#contains when I only have a BigInteger?

Tags: java, types, contains, biginteger

I am pulling data values from a database that returns a List of `<Integer>`.  However, I would like to see if the List contains my BigInteger.  Is there a simple way to do this?

I currently have the following code in Java:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(new Integer(29415));}};

boolean contains = arr.contains(29415); // true
boolean contains2 = arr.contains(new BigInteger("29415")); // false
```

I'm not sure on an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "efficient".  ArrayList.contains just does a linear search of its elements.  If you want `efficient` searching, you'll need to consider some other structure, e.g., one that's hashed.

Comment: By efficient, I mean: Is there a way to get a correct solution without having to cast the 'arr' to hold <BigInteger>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer will be returned by evaluation of the following:

```
val != null 
  && BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE).compareTo(val) < 0 
  && BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).compareTo(val) > 0 
  && list.contains(val.intValue())
```

This will correctly solve the question of whether the `BigInteger` you have is "contained" within the `List<Integer>`. Note that here we only downcast where necessary. If the `val` is outside the range of `Integer` values there is no need to downcast as we know that the value *cannot* be within the list.

A more relevant question is whether you should actually be using a `List<BigInteger>` in place of a `List<Integer>` but that is a different question and not part of the answer to your explicit question

Answer (score 3):

While arshajii provides a solution which works, i would vote against it.
You should never downcast values. You are running in danger of your program producing larger values which translate to invalid values when downcasted. This kind of bug will be super nasty to troubleshoot months later.

If your code works with BigInteger, then you should convert all values from the database into BigInteger. This is an upcast where you cannot loose values.
Overall I would value correctness over efficiency. If at all, I would reconsider your usage of BigInteger (maybe long is fine?) but because you have it, I assume you have a reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java `List.contains()` uses the `equals()` method internally and because `BigInteger.equals(Integer)` returns false, your `List.contains()` also returns false. Either use the an `List<BigInteger>` or extract the Int value from BigInteger (as arshajii explained!). Of course, if you really want to search effectively, you should think of a binary search (in a sorted list) or of another data structure like `Map`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? PS: This question will remain here as long as the downvote remains.

Comment: +1 because the point is valid indeed, and has no reason to be downvoted.

Comment: I downvoted because I dont have the control to cast to BigInteger (unless I do it explicitly)...but you are correct, edit your answer and i'll vote up.

Comment: @Kamilski81 Done: updated my answer. Also for the future: a bad put/incomplete question should have nothing to to with an answer that covers multiple use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`BigInteger#intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue--):

```
arr.contains(myBigInteger.intValue())
```

Note, however, that if `myBigInteger` is too big to fit into an `int`, then only the lower 32 bits will be returned (as described in the linked docs). Therefore, you might want to check if `myBigInteger` is less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` before checking for containment.

Comment: But don't forget to ensure your BigInteger never contains any numbers greater than int.